# Using Button Intents on Android

Tags: android

I want to make an app. I'm using Eclipse. I have four activities.

MainActivity = buttonStart

Activity1 = button1

Activity2 = button2

Activity3 = button3

for now, when calling button1, button2, button3 must be pressed.

I want to make something like this..

1. If buttonStart pressed then directly it will execute button1 for 10 secs.
2. When the button1's time is out (10 secs). Then it will jump to button2 automatically for 10 secs.
3. When the button2's time is out (10 secs). Then it will jump to button3 automatically for 10 secs.

MainActivity

```
Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), classForButton1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }
                });
```

ACTIVITY1

```
Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), classForButton2.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }
                });
```

ACTIVITY2

```
Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), classForButton2.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }
                });
```

ACTIVITY3

```
Button prev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
            prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();

                }
                });
```

Comment: Try TimerTask on button 1 click and startactivity based on a constant incremental variable

Comment: What are you trying to do? any why do you startActivityForResult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can help you.

```
Button btn_1 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
final Button btn_2 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
final Button btn_3 = new Button(getApplicationContext());

btn_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // PERFORM YOUR WORK HERE
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                btn_2.performClick();
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(task, 10000);
    }
});

btn_2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // PERFORM YOUR WORK HERE
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                btn_3.performClick();
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(task, 10000);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Its a simple example to help you. you can optimize yourself according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

To do this I don't think you need more thean one button, use only one button in first activity, Use timertask to trigger startActivity(A) after 10  sec, then on second activity's oncreate method use timerTask to trigger startActivity(B) and do the same for third activity also.

Comment: can you give me an example to implement timer task on my code above?